# Do two processes of same application run on same VM?

Tags: android

I am using "android:process"  to let an application have two processes.
My question is, Do both processes run in one vm or in two vms?

Answer (score 2):

From Professional Android 4 Application Development By Reto Meier:

*By default, each Android application runs in its own process, each of which is running a separate
instance of Dalvik. Memory and process management is handled exclusively by the run time.
You can force application components within the same application to run in different
processes or to have multiple applications share the same process using
the android:process attribute on the affected component nodes within the
manifest.*